# Function gives me back wrong number

Tags: c, function

I have a problem with this code, it gives me in output the wrong number, when I put for example 5, it gives me back 5. It doesn't make sense because I want the sum of the numbers between 0 and x.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void suma_n_nums(int n);

int main() {
    int x;
    printf("Introduzca un numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    suma_n_nums(x);
    return 0;
}

void suma_n_nums(int n) {
    int i;
    int suma;
    if (n > 0) {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            suma += i;
        }
    }
    printf("El resultado de la suma es: %d", suma);
}
```

Comment: Please format your code. And initialize `suma` to zero.

Comment: Please sort out the formatting of this question. The code insert tool will help

Comment: Hint: Uninitialized local variables really *are* uninitialized, and will have an *indeterminate* value.

Comment: Would somebody like to get the indentation fixed - I have removed the spurious blank lines

Comment: Please try to write better description text for your question in future. Take time to check your spelling and formatting. Other people will take time to answer...

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the return value from `scanf`

You want something like

```
if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1) {
  fprintf("You have not entered a valid number\n");
  retrun -1;
}
```

2. Initialise variables

   ```
   int suma = 0;
   ```
3. For extra credit - dump the for loop

   ```
   int suma = (n * (1 + n)) / 2;
   ```

With this in mind the code could be

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("Introduzca un numero: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &x) == 1) {
      printf("El resultado de la suma es: %d", (x * (x + 1)/2);
      return 0;
    } else {
      fprintf("You have not entered a valid number\n");
      retrun -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void suma_n_nums(int n);

int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("Introduzca un numero: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Scanf failure\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    suma_n_nums(x);
    return 0;
}

void suma_n_nums(int n) {
    int i, suma = 0;
    if (n > 0) {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            suma += i;
        }
        printf("El resultado de la suma es: %d\n", suma);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Number must be bigger than 0\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

You must always check the return value of `scanf`,
I also added a check for the negative values; if there is a negative value in input, the program exit with an error message.